# Make a 0.5 HP, 3-phase motor work with single phase voltage with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, three-phase, vfd

I have a MGM Varvel's SM71B4 AC motor which runs on 3-phase that comes out of a Schneider Electric's VFD called Altivar ATV12H037M2. The VFD has failed and doesn't show the input voltage, so I decided to run the motor directly without VFD.

Here I'm not sure how I turn single-phase mains into 3-phase using capacitors. I have read a few articles but am not clear about the connections.

I'm attaching few pics:

[Motor input 3 phase vfd connections](https://imgur.com/a/GwnehVp)

[Motor description](https://imgur.com/a/9laiY2a)

[Capacitors inside Schneider VFD](https://imgur.com/a/WKKRL4q)